# Why won't my font change color?

Tags: css

Here is my HTML:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: italic;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Geneva, Arial, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p {
  font-family: Georgia, “Times New Roman”, Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
p.important {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.typewriter {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
.emphasized {
  font-style: italic;
}
.standout {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Jen</h1>
<h2>That’s my name</h2>
<p class=“important”>This is a bunch of text</p>
<h2 class="typewriter">This heading is in a typewriter text.</h2>
<p class="typewriter">This paragraph is also in typewriter text.</p>
<p>This is <span class="emphasized">italicized text</span> for learning purposes.</p>
<p>This is going to be <span class=“standout”> red colored text</span> for learning purposes.</p>
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is and I've tried everything I can think of...

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I am new to web design and I am doing my best to learn on my own....but I need some help for this please.

Comment: Because you are using curly quotes in `class=“standout”`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct quotes:

```
<span class=“standout”>

<span class="standout">
```

Comment: To add to this, macOS will replace quotation marks with curly "smart quotes" by default in some applications. The setting is easy to disable if you Google the issue.